# How do you convert video within 10.7 without any 3rd party software

Tags: macos, video, encoding

Is it possible to convert video resolution within 10.7 without the use of Handbrake.app or other 3rd party software? I'm not allowed to install any apps on this machine so hence not being able to download Handbrake.app

Answer (score 12):

Yes it's possible, just right click on the video file within finder and choose the encode selected video files.

[image: Right click on video file]
[image: Choose resolution]
[image: click continue]

Comment: Very nice find! You might add this tip to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17759/what-tiny-thing-in-lion-makes-you-smile-or-has-caught-you-off-guard

Comment: Note: This is now under the "Services" section in the menu

Comment: If the service is missing, activate it in the System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Services.