# Is there an easy way to reduce quality of .mov files taken from an iPhone?

Tags: macos, iphone, video, quicktime, encoding

I've noticed the small movies I take on my iPhone 4 result in large .mov files. For example, a 1 minute movie results in almost a 100MB .mov file. This is running through my cloud storage (Dropbox) rather quickly. Is there an easy way to reduce the quality/size after transferring to my Mac?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Most of this is documented:

- [How do you convert video within 10.7 without any 3rd party software](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21737/how-do-you-convert-video-within-10-7-without-any-3rd-party-software)

[image: Right click on video file]
[image: Choose resolution]
[image: click continue]

The Finder has built in video encoding and you could even use these to set up watch folders and attach a pre-set conversion using Automator if you found one setting that you prefer...

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to using Quicktime to lower the quality of the video (therefore, reduce the size of the file) is to use VLC Media Player.

It works better in the sense that it provides options for codecs, encapsulation and audio codecs as well. This can help to convert the .mov to be playable in specific devices or platforms.

***Moreover***, it keeps a better resolution of the videos.

[image]

Comment: This is the only option that is working for me. I tried to convert 720p files using the latest versions of iMovie, Quicktime and an old program that I used to use a lot. At 540p they created these huge files almost three times the size of the original. With VLC the new file is 75% the size of the original with really good quality.

Answer (score 0):

You can transcode them while transferring!

You can do exactly same automator workflow but make it an Image Capture plug-in. So you can choose in "Image Capture" videos from your iOS device and import them transcoded.

Really easy steps are presented on [macworld.com](http://www.macworld.com/article/1163361/smaller_iphones4s_movies.html), basically you use

[image]

and import your movies using Image Capture.

If you check the box [Show this action when the workflow runs] you will be able to choose destination folder and compress options.