# How can I tell what is using disk space by category and monitor changes?

Tags: macos, disk-space

Is there a simple way to determine what is using disk space on a Mac OS X installation?  Obviously single files and directories is straightforward, but how about at a slightly higher level customisable overview for the whole of your drive?

Is it possible to get a sort of "management overview" of your drive that for example shows % space used, and than breaks that down into something simple to understand like:

```
90% of 100Gb used total, of which:
20Gb is Applications
30Gb is iTunes
12Gb is Photos
5Gb is Application Support files
13Gb is OS files
10Gb is other Home Directory contents
```

Bonus points is there is a simple way to also track this information over time, for example:

```
90% of 100Gb used total, of which:
20Gb is Applications, 20% increase since last month
30Gb is iTunes, 10% increase since last month
12Gb is Photos, No change
5Gb is Application Support files, 3% decrease since last month
13Gb is OS files No change
10Gb is other Home Directory contents, 4% increase since last month
```

Obviously all figures are pulled out of a hat.

To be clear, I am looking at sensibly grouped collections of files, not full on listings of every directory by name.  DaisyDisk is excellent, but it doesn't really fit the bill for what I am looking for.  Crazy detail isn't what I need, just a management overview of space for a high level "audit" of space for want of a better word.

Comment: How would you refine your need past the canonical Lion storage overview bar graph? http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/18444/5472 I use that [WhatSize](http://whatsizemac.com/) and [BackupLoupe](http://soma-zone.com/BackupLoupe/) to monitor changes over time.

Comment: In a word, customisation.  What does the bar graph mean my pictures?  My iPhoto libraries, or all gifs on the drive?  I would like to be able to select what goes into what category, or at least *view* what makes a file eligible for one over another.  Imagine a music app with a library of samples.  Is that app data, application support files, or music?  I would like to define or view that detail.

Comment: Would a shell script work? The only problem is that you can't really get the customization you ask for with the question your asking. As in, the question states you want a simple inventory of those directories, but your comment seems that you want data split out for the same file types.